# navigation buttons li span width

Tags: navigation, width, html-lists, css-transitions, html

I have a nav containing inline block li's. Each li contains two block span elements so it animates on rollover. My issue is with the centre alignment and spacing of the li navigation. I don't want to give the li tags a min width. Can anyone help with this?

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="button">

                <a href="#">
                    <span class="top">Home</span>
                    <span class="bottom">Home</span>
                </a>

        </li>

        <li class="button"> 

                <a href="#">
                    <span class="top">About</span>
                    <span class="bottom">About</span>
                </a>

        </li>

        <li class="button">

                <a href="#">
                    <span class="top">Equine</span>
                    <span class="bottom">Equine</span>
                </a>

        </li>

        <li class="button">

                <a href="#">
                    <span class="top">Canine</span>
                    <span class="bottom">Canine</span>
                </a>

        </li>

        <li class="button">

                <a href="#">
                    <span class="top">Rates & Travel</span>
                    <span class="bottom">Rates & Travel</span>
                </a>

        </li>

        <li class="button">

                <a href="#">
                    <span class="top">Case Study & News</span>
                    <span class="bottom">Case Study & News</span>
                </a>
        </li>

</div> <!---nav---->
```

CSS:

```
#nav {
height: 25px;
border-top: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
border-bottom: 1px solid #C7C7C7;
padding: 10px 0px 5px 0px;
text-align: center;


}

#nav li{
height: 16px;
line-height: 15px;
overflow: hidden;
display: inline-block;
padding: 0px 25px 0px 25px;
position: relative;
}

li span.top {
color: #16528e;
top: -18px;

}

a:hover span {
top: 18px;
}
a:hover span.top {
top: 0;
}

li span {
display: block;
top: 0;
position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.3s, border 0.3s, color 0.35s;
  -moz-transition: top 0.3s, border 0.3s, color 0.35s;
  -ms-transition: top 0.3s, border 0.3s, color 0.35s;
  -o-transition: top 0.3s, border 0.3s, color 0.35s;
  transition: top 0.3s, border 0.3s, color 0.35s;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `position:absolute` is creating this issue under `li span`. You need to remove it and you will get your effect by applying the negative `top` to this css.

For Instance,

```
li span {

   display: block;
   position: relative;
   top: -15px;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.3s, border 0.3s, color 0.35s;
  -moz-transition: top 0.3s, border 0.3s, color 0.35s;
  -ms-transition: top 0.3s, border 0.3s, color 0.35s;
  -o-transition: top 0.3s, border 0.3s, color 0.35s;
  transition: top 0.3s, border 0.3s, color 0.35s;
}
```

Here is the [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/spkUc/).

Hope this Helps.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the solution, you can accept it by a green tick and upvote. Thank you - @user1910388